# Problems with threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm newer with Threads and I need to fix this error could you help me?

**Sorry was my fault this is what I have to do:**

**This web application must execute 1000 games and show the output results.**

My apologize again.

Thanks

```
/**
 * 
 * Automatic agent to play 1000 games
 * 
 */
public class AutoPlayer implements Runnable {

    private RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher;

    public AutoPlayer(RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher) {
    this.requestDispatcher = requestDispatcher;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, Game> games = new HashMap<String, Game>();

    RequestDispatcher rd = new RequestDispatcher(games);

    Vector<Thread> threads = new Vector<Thread>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        AutoPlayer autoPlayer = new AutoPlayer(rd);
        Thread thread = new Thread(autoPlayer);
        threads.add(thread);
        thread.start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
        try {
        threads.get(i).join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }



    @Override
    public void run() {

    PlayResponse response = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        byte[] numbers = requestDispatcher.cardRequest();

        try {
        response = new PlayResponse();
        requestDispatcher.process("Lucky", 10, numbers, response);
        } catch (UnknownGameException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (response != null) {
        System.out.println("[" + Thread.currentThread() + "] total requests:" + requestDispatcher.generatedCards);
        }
    }
    }

}



public class Game {

    private String name;
    private int gamesPlayed;

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public int getGamesPlayed() {
    return gamesPlayed;
    }

    public void setGamesPlayed(int gamesPlayed) {
    this.gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed;
    }

}



/**
 * 
 * Response to a Play request
 * 
 */
public class PlayResponse {

    private boolean error;
    private long win;

    public boolean isError() {
        return error;
    }
    public void setError(boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
    public long getWin() {
        return win;
    }
    public void setWin(long win) {
        this.win = win;
    }

}




/**
 * 
 * Object that processes play requests, calculates outcomes and returns results.
 * 
 */
public class RequestDispatcher {

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Lucky", "Happy", "Extra");

    final int CARD_SIZE = 15;

    public String GAME_UNAVAILABLE = "Error: Game not available";

    Map<String, Game> games;

    long generatedCards;

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    Random r = new Random();

    public RequestDispatcher(HashMap<String, Game> games) {
    this.games = games;

    }

    public byte[] cardRequest() {
    byte[] result = createCard();
    generatedCards++;

    return result;
    }

    private byte[] createCard() {

    byte[] result = new byte[CARD_SIZE];

    r.nextBytes(result);

    return result;
    }

    public void process(String s, int i, byte[] bb, PlayResponse pr0) throws UnknownGameException {

    if (!list.contains(s)) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, GAME_UNAVAILABLE);
        throw new UnknownGameException(GAME_UNAVAILABLE);
    }

    Game game = games.get(s);

    if (game != null) {
        game.setGamesPlayed(game.getGamesPlayed() + 1);
    } else {
        Game g = new Game();
        g.setName(s);
        games.put(s, g);
        g.setGamesPlayed(0);
    }

    pr0.setWin(r.nextInt(3) * i);
    pr0.setError(false);

    }
}


public class UnknownGameException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2380720995275983122L;

    public UnknownGameException(String s) {
    super(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. Could you provide a minimal working example? Please also take a look at http://sscce.org

Comment: please prune/reduce the size of your code. Do methods setError, getName, getWin, setWin, have any relevance to the problem you have? People will ignore this question if you have too much code.

Comment: eg. the logger in your code has NO bearing on the question you are asking. remove it.

Comment: how are you validating 1000 threads, loop starts 10 threads which main thread join and these threads doesn't start any more thread??

Comment: It seems like what is going on is that the code in `run` needs to be executed a total of `1000` times using `10` threads. Is that correct? Why not make the loop `1 - 100` x 10 threads = 1000?

Comment: Did you intend for all 10 threads to share a single `RequestDispatcher`? If so you need to add in some synchronization to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 1):

The code creates 10 threads in `main`. Each thread plays 1000 games in `run`. That gives a total of 10 * 1000 = 10000 games.

To change the number of games just change those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are needing to execute `run` 1000 times using 10 threads consider the following options.

1. Make each thread execute 100 times.
2. Use a static counter that is shared between the threads a stop executing when the counter hits 1000. Make sure you use an `AtomicInteger` for the counter to ensure that it is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are creating  10 threads in main. 
           Just change the number of threads and use synchronization for the shared fields and methods.